# How to get data from server Alamofire swift with header

Tags: json, swift, get, alamofire

When I want to get data from the server using `Alamofire` it shows me some error I want to get data from the server using the header in my header I pass id and token.

```
@IBAction func profile(_ sender: Any) {

    print(AuthService.instance.authToken)
    print(AuthService.instance.userEmail)
    let BEARER_HEADER2 = [
        "id":AuthService.instance.userEmail,
        "Authorization":AuthService.instance.authToken

        //"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    ]
    print(BEARER_HEADER2)

    Alamofire.request("http://fiveorzero.ml/api/v1/user/user/profile",method: .get, parameters: nil,encoding:URLEncoding.default, headers: BEARER_HEADER2).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            let swiftyJson = JSON(value)
            print(swiftyJson)
            print("Khabbab")

        case .failure(let error):
            debugPrint(response.result.error as Any)
            print ("error: \(error)")
        }
    }

}
```

> $2y$10$CUWgHVpbt6oPUdBo7weofucUniXw9JZoIeWZ1hZiwAfymZASoNWyS
>       128
>       ["id": "128", "Authorization": "$2y$10$CUWgHVpbt6oPUdBo7weofucUniXw9JZoIeWZ1hZiwAfymZASoNWyS"]
>       Optional(Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.})))
>       error: responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))

Comment: try replacing `responseJSON` with `responseString`

Comment: Are u passing headers in same format which your server required?

Comment: yes the server want to token and id

Comment: still, it doesn't work

Comment: ["id": "128", "Authorization": "$2y$10$CUWgHVpbt6oPUdBo7weofucUniXw9JZoIeWZ1hZiwAfymZASoNWyS"]
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Page Not Found</title>

Comment: ["id": "128", "authorization": "$2y$10$8O7D5eUdyFHi6heOQIws8uNcMhWbaZgyzPN4CCdLrjP.5e75Fl76W"]
Authentication Token not Matched!

Answer (score 0):

```
 Alamofire.request(URL, method: .get, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON
                {
                    response in
                    switch response.result
                    {
                    case .success(let value):
                        completionHandler(value as? Array, nil)//completionHandler(value as? NSDictionary, nil)
                    print(value)
                    case .failure(let error):
                        completionHandler(nil,(error as NSError?)!)
                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this for create header

```
let id = "your id"
let Authorization = "your ascess token"
let credentialData = "\(id):\(Authorization)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedString(options: [])
    let headers = ["Authorization": "Basic \(base64Credentials)"]

Alamofire.request("your url" , method : .post, parameters: parameters,
                      headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in
        // do whatever you want here
        switch response.result {
        case .failure(let error): break
        // self.popupp(elrtdata : "Please try again latter.")
        case .success(let responseObject): } }
```

Comment: Doesn't work it says Authentication Token not Matched! but in postman, I can access my user profile by using Authorization token and id